# API to lookup by CUSIP

Tags: api, web-apis

I'm looking for an API that takes a CUSIP and returns some information about that bond, annuity, or other financial product. The particular thing I'm looking for is product type, so a request should take 74430T119 and very little else (I also know allowed states and a 3-digit abbreviation of the carrier, so if needed I could pass those to the API), and return at least:

```
{
  "CUSIP":"74430T119"
  "productType":"Variable Annuity"
  ...
}
```

Format can change, but the point is I want to match CUSIPs with product types, and **the API must work for CUSIPs like 74430T119**.

Answer (score 2):

Vay Studio provides a free CUSIP lookup API for United States securities.

https://vay.studio/explore/cusip-lookup/

They collect their data from the SEC.

Comment: Getting closer, but that API only works if the security has a ticker symbol. Other products, for instance annuities like 74430T119, give a server error.

Answer (score 1):

When someone asks about a web API to do something, I've always found an answer on [ProgrammableWeb](https://www.programmableweb.com/).

In this case, the US Dept. of the Treasury can help you out - but there are 2 others related to CUSIP.

https://www.programmableweb.com/api/treasurydirect-security-information

Comment: that is really close, but I don't know issue dates. I don't see why that has to be a required parameter in the API...

Comment: @NH. no idea here either, but it may be that they provide the service for folks where date is known, like stock buy/sell dates to determine initial cost basis...  If just entering yesterday (or some other valid date) gets the API to give you what you want, I'd just call it the cost of doing business and move on with life...

Comment: oh, I see... Issue dates are required because this API only works for treasury securities. Apparently annuities (what I needed) aren't included.

Answer (score 1):

Treasury API works only for Govt/Debt securities. Another alternative is to use OpenFIGI. It supports lookup by many identifiers including CUSIP. 
https://www.openfigi.com/api

To access the API key, it requires an institutional email id for sign-up. Free email accounts such as Gmail/Hotmail are not accepted. That is a small caveat.